# Excel VBA scripts/macros to Google Spreadsheets scripts/macros

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vba

Our company moved to G suite, I now have a handful of Excel VBA scripts/macros. Can anyone help me how do I use the VBA functionality in Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi Vel, welcome to Stack Overflow. You're question is too broad as it currently stands. What issue, specifically, are you having with VBA functionality in Google Spreadsheets? (Perhaps take a gander at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get an idea of how to improve your question)

Comment: It's a completely different environment and scripting is done 100% differently. This isn't something you can just get help with. I would suggest planning out some time to learn how it's done in google sheets, then figuring out how to replicate your current VBA stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use VBA functionality in Google a spreadsheet as Google Sheets use Google Apps Script which runs on the server, not locally, and it's based on JavaScript not in Visual Basic.